# CRLF tags attached upon FTP upload from a windows to Linux Server

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, ftp

I am uploading the files in a FTP folder from Windows server to a Linux server. Files come in different extensions but can be opened using notepad or notpad++.
I am getting issues that `CR` & `CRLF` are getting attached after FTP upload to Linux from Windows.

I am uploading a file from windows in the below format[image]

This is the file after FTP Upload to Linux server. We can see many `CR` and `CRLF` tags getting attached, which shouldn't be the case.

[image]

I need the files in the below format in Linux (With only `LF` tags attached)

[image]

For FTP from windows to Linux, I am using the Batch Script as below..

```
open XXXXXXXXXX.net
UID
PASSWORD 
cd METS
cd MARVELRAIL
binary
mput E:\METS+_BULK_UPLOAD\BULK_FOLDERS\OUT\DISCH\*.*
quit
```

Can you help me where I am going wrong and how to beat this issue...
Thank in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the files to be converted to *nix line endings, do not use a binary mode, use an ascii mode.

The ascii mode is the default one, so removing `binary` command should be enough.

Or you can explicitly use `ascii` command.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your answer. So the `LF` tag gets attached automatically using ASCII transfer there. So I do not need to append `\n` at the end of every line..?

Comment: Nothing is **appended**. Windows use CRLF. And during *ascii* transfer to *nix-based system, CRLF is **replaced** with LF.